# Forcing Function and its Particular Solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am attempting to find a particular solution to the forcing function:
f(t)=2te^tsint, but I have been stuck for a bit. Does anyone know the correct path to find the particular solution. Should I separate each term?

I got:
At+Bte^t+ C cos(t) + D(sint)

Comment: Where is the DEQ?

Comment: the differential equation is y'' +2y'-3y=2te^sint

Comment: I assume you meant to write $$y'' +2y'-3y=2te^t \sin t $$ Choose $$y_p = e^t(a \cos t + b \sin t + c ~t \cos t + d ~t \sin t)$$